# Light Box only one image loads, 3 others do not

Tags: lightbox, image-gallery, responsive-images

Hi I am redesigning my website, I am a novice at JS and CSS, pretty good with HTML 5.  I am working on a new responsive web site with a gallery page of images using Lightbox.

The Beta Site and Gallery Page is here:
**http://www.sound-enclosures.com/FanAir/index-3.html**

I have a Link to " img  src= " to the Thumbnail and a "a  href= " to the BIG Image.

Problem is only One of Four Images load. It's the First Image on the Page The Blue Picture.  This seems to work correctly.  The other Images try to link, however they just Hang Up on Loading.  I have verified the file names, locations, checked the URL's etc.

I am using Lightbox.min. script before "/head"  and bootstrap.min.js at the bottom of my page before "/body"

The Monster Template I am using was furnished with jQuery v1.11.1, 
I have read in the Stackoverflow Forums that JQuery 1.8 seems to work better with Lightbox, I have not tried that and would be reluctant to do so as it might mess up other pages.

Can any one take a look and possibly provide some assistance, guidance?

Thank you all in advance.

Scotty

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read [How to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide some more code infos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your images do not load because they are either not on your server or not in the folder *images*

There is no image named: *page4_pic15_Big.jpg* that is set as your href:

```
<a href="images/page4_pic15_Big.jpg" data-title="Heavy Duty Centrifugal Blower" rel="lightbox"> <img src="images/page4_pic15.jpg">
                    Backward Inclined Blowers<br>
                  </a>
```

Comment: Hi MacSupport:   Thanks a Million, with your help I got it working.  Allthough the Images were in the correct location, in my "images" folder on my server, you sort of jogged my thinking !   I thought that I might just try and use the absolute full URL, such as:  "http://0397d5c.netsolhost.com/FanAir/images/page4_pic17_BIG.jpg"  I just copied the full URL with FTP Voyager and chanhed the ftp" to "http"  and that worked fantastically.  Awesome  Thank you, thank you !! :)

Comment: IF it answered your question, go ahead and mark it answered.  ;-)